# how to deallocate stack in ucontext* , linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack, memory-management

so I am trying to deallocate the context.

Here is how I created context

```
ucontext* uPtr = new ucontext;
getcontext(uPtr);

char* stack = new char[STACK_SIZE];
uPtr->uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
uPtr->uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
uPtr->uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
uPtr->uc_link = NULL;

makecontext(uPtr, (void (*)()) func, 2, arg1, arg2);
```

after I create the context like above, I use it and try to delete when I am done
but I can't figure out how to delete uPtr->uc_stack.ss_sp.

I tried

```
delete[] foo; //suppose I saved the char* stack in foo
```

but it gave me seg fault

and when I tried

```
delete[] (char*)uPtr->uc_stack.sS_sp;
```

I don't think it properly deletes the stack.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: i dont quite understand what exactly foo is.Is it a ucontext type or char*?and whats going on when u attempt delete[](char*)uPtr->uc_stack.ss_sp?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to delete the stack after the context is no longer used, and assuming you haven't modified the context object pointed to by `uPtr` in the mean time then

```
delete [] (char*)uPtr->uc_stack.ss_sp;
```

should work: you allocated the memory with `new[]`, so you deallocate it with `delete[]`. Why do you think it doesn't?